# USB library for Julia language

Tags: library, usb, julia

Is there a USB library for Julia language? Something similar to pyusb in python.

I have tried a search online but I could only find SerialPorts that actually uses pyserial python library via PyCall.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use PyCall library in Julia to import usb library from Python

```
import PyCall
usb = PyCall.pyimport("usb")
```

the resulting usb object is what you can use to communicate with usb devices in the same way you do it with Python.